# Complex NodeJS / Express REGEX routing

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create a NodeJS Express API (route) which has the following characteristics:

It has a base path, in my case it is `/web/views`. This part is a static value and doesn't change for as long as the server is up.

I can do this as follows:

```
const BASE = '/web/views';    // defined externally/elsewhere 

app.get(BASE, function handleRequest(req, res) {
    // handle API request...
}
```

Next, I expect to be provided with a resource. Given the name of this resource, I locate a file and send it to the client.

I can do this as follows:

```
app.get(BASE + '/:resource', function handleRequest(req, res) {
    var resource = req.params.resource;
    // handle API request...
}
```

So on the client, I invoke it this way:

```
GET /web/views/header
```

All of this works so far... but my problem is that my 'resource' can actually be a path in itself, such as:

```
GET /web/views/menu/dashboard
```

or a longer path, such as:

```
GET /web/views/some/long/path/to/my/xyz
```

I was using the following REGEX mapping:

```
const DEFAULT_REGEX = '/(\*/)?:resource';
```

or more precisely:

```
app.get(BASE + DEFAULT_REGEX, function handleRequest(req, res) {
    var resource = req.params.resource;
    // handle API request...
}
```

This works with an arbitrary length path between my `BASE` value and the `:resource` identifier, but the problem is that my `resource` variable only has 
the `xyz` portion of the path and not the full path (ie: `/some/long/path/to/my/xyz`).

I could simply cheat and strip the leading `BASE` from the `req.url`, but I though there would be a REGEX rule for it.

If anyone knows how to do such advanced REGEX routing, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, so I think the easiest way is to simply not worry about using Regex, but instead just use a wildcard.  You lose the cool params name, but otherwise it works as you're looking for.  For example:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const BASE = '/web/views'

app.get(`${BASE}/*`, (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.url);
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

If you hit `http://localhost:3000/web/views/path/to/my/resource`, in my example the response content will be `/web/views/path/to/my/resource`, so from there it's some simple string manipulation to pull the bit you want:

```
let resource = req.url.split('/web/views')[1];
// resource will equal /path/to/my/resource if the above URL is used
```

Of course you could get fancier with your string parsing to check for errors and such, but you get the idea.

You could even setup a middleware to get that resource piece for other handlers to work from:

```
app.use(`${BASE}/*`, (req, res, next) => {
   const resource = req.url.split(BASE)[1];
   req.resource = resource;
   next();
});
```

Then all subsequent routes will have access to `req.resource`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Paul, I'll explore your suggestion. I had no idea you could use ``${BASE}/*`` for variables ... I used it in BASH regularly but never in JavaScript.

Comment: It's a relatively new feature, doesn't necessarily work with browser JavaScript and only works when you're using the templating string approach (the backticks). But it's handy!

Comment: For the pirpyof you're question, though, it's syntactic sugar. The same thing will work with string concatenation.